# Rotate when hover on navigation and stay when clicked. When clicked on other navigation, siblings rotate back to original position

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, rotation, hover

I'd like to have a text(navigation) rotate 45 degrees on hover. When the text is clicked/selected I'd like the text to remain in that position. When the user clicks on the other nav, then the siblings class will be removed and rotated back to 0deg. Anyone can offer a solution?

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav li a").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");});
    });
    </script>`

HTML:

`<nav class="desktop">
    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about" title="Next Section">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" title="Next Section">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#homepage" title="Next Section"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#works" title="Next Section">WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" title="Next Section">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>`

```
.desktop #nav li
{
display:inline-block;
width:150px;
font-size:120%;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s;  For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 
transition:transform 0.5s;
}

.desktop #nav li:hover, .active
{
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}`
```

Comment: whats wrong with the current solution ?

Comment: Firstly, when hover, it rotates 45 deg. When clicked, it will rotate another 45 deg which means 90 deg then it goes back to 45 deg and stay.

The siblings too doesnt work. The other list doesnt go back to 0deg.
Would appreciate if someone could help me... Really stuck!

Comment: i suspect that CSS3 needs to be tuned a bit, could you create a jsfiddle,will have a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/rezasan/vSJCw/

Comment: is this what you wanted ? jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/vSJCw/6/

Comment: Thanks to gulty. He managed to solve the problem. Thanks gulty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your Javascript part:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
```

You want to access the child elements of the lists. $(this) is the anchor tag you click on and therefor there are no siblings inside this li element.

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().each(function () {
        $(this).children().removeClass("active");
    });
})
```

This gets the parent list element and is afterwards iterating through the other li's child-elements to remove the active class.

I pasted your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u276x/) - it is pretty ugly and not styled properly but you can see the javascript works.

Edit: The problem with your 90° is that you apply the CSS transition to your li element. Thats why on hover your li element is rotating and on click the anchor inside the li is rotating as well.

A better approach to mine is to put the active class on the list element so you dont have to change anything on the css since the click will prevent the hover from working.

See here: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u276x/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".nav li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
})
```

});

Comment: THE BEST ANSWER! Thanks so much! Phew. I can leave the office now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS to this :

```
.desktop #nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer
}

.desktop #nav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
} 

.desktop #nav li:hover a, .desktop #nav li.active a{
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

and jQuery code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".nav li").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    }); 
});
```

The problem with your code was, when you hover to the `<li>` tag, it rotates to 45deg so it will move out of the cursor area. So hover out event will be fired and `<li>` tag will again rotate to 0deg. Again it comes in cursor area and this goes forever !

Here you can rotate `<a>` tag instead of `<li>` tag and it will do the work.

Working Demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/VQ2x2/7/**

Comment: your fiddle isnt working at all for me. no hover and no click effects - your approach on the js is correct tho

Comment: @gulty : I forgot to add vendor specific prefixes for transform property. The updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VQ2x2/2/

Comment: Hey it somehow works. But when the other nav class is removed, it doesn't spin(animate). It just rotate 45deg. No transition. Hmm..

Comment: @RezaSan : Updated the Fiddle Link and Answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Just one last question. If let's say I clicked About, it will rotate 45deg. When I click on About again, it will rotate back to 0 deg. Is there a way I can prevent it? Only when I click other navigation then About can turn back to 0 deg. Same for the other links. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I know i need to do some conditional statements or some boolean? Will work on that. Right?

Comment: @RezaSan : Yes, just replace the  $(this).toggleClass("active") with  $(this).addClass("active").
Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah! Got it! You're brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I think you had mistaken in your code. The code should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nav li a").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
   });
});
```

OR

you may also try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nav li a").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");  //It will remove active class from all anchor elements.
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
   });
});
```